# XSL to transform simple HTML table to InDesign Table (for XML import)

Tags: xml, xslt, adobe-indesign

I was wondering if anyone here ever needed to transform a simple HTML table (in a XML that will be imported to InDesign) to an InDesign table, something like this:

Here's the input (simplified):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<publication xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/">

      <text>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>
        <hr/>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="width:500px">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Topic 1</th>
                    <th>Topic 2</th>
                    <th>Topic 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>111</td>
                    <td>222</td>
                    <td>3333</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1111</td>
                    <td>2222</td>
                    <td>3333</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </text>

</publication>
```

And here's the expected output:

```xml
<Table aid5:tablestyle="custom_table" style="width:500px" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" aid:table="table" aid:trows="5" aid:tcols="3">
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">Topic 1</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">Topic 2</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">Topic 3</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">1</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">2</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">3</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">11</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">22</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">33</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">111</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">222</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">333</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">1111</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">2222</Cell>
    <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">3333</Cell>
</Table>
```

And here is the XSL I attempted so far:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/"
xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="table">
    <Tabla aid:table="table" aid5:tablestyle="tabla">
        <xsl:attribute name="aid:tcols">
          <xsl:for-each select=".//tr">
            <xsl:sort select="count(td)" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
              <xsl:value-of select="count(td)"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="aid:trows">
          <xsl:for-each select=".//tbody">
            <xsl:sort select="count(tr)" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
              <xsl:value-of select="count(tr)"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Tabla>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="th | tr | td | thead | tbody">
        <Cell>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::th | self::tr | self::td | self::thead | self::tbody)]"/>
        </Cell>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="th | tr | td " />
</xsl:template>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But that produces duplicated Tags and it's likely not correct:

```xml
<Table aid:table="table" aid5:tablestyle="tabla" aid:tcols="3" aid:trows="4" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="width:500px">
  <Cell />
  <Cell />
  <Cell>asa</Cell>
  <Cell>asdsd</Cell>
  <Cell>asdads</Cell>
  <Cell />
  <Cell />
  <Cell>d</Cell>
  <Cell>dd</Cell>
  <Cell>ddd</Cell>
  <Cell />
  <Cell>d</Cell>
  <Cell>dd</Cell>
  <Cell>ddd</Cell>
  <Cell />
  <Cell>d</Cell>
  <Cell>dd</Cell>
  <Cell>ddd</Cell>
  <Cell />
  <Cell>d</Cell>
  <Cell>dd</Cell>
  <Cell>ddd</Cell>
</Table>
```

By far the hardest part has been to "flatten" the Table hierarchy to match what InDesign expects, i haven't used XSL in ages (since i was a Coldfusion programmer) and honestly forgot all about it.

Hope someone here can help, thanks.

Comment: Well, flattening is easy for that sample as you just would need to process e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="*/tr/*"/>` from your template matching the `table`. But things get complicated as soon as there can be any use of `rowspan` or `colspan` inside of the HTML table.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yeah, that was my first approach but I never got it to work, about `rowspan` and `colspan`  I see how that would get complicated really fast, luckily they won't be using that (any really complex tables will be done by a designer in Illustrator and then imported as vector graphics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/"
xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
<xsl:template match="/publication">
    <Table aid5:tablestyle="custom_table" style="width:500px" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" aid:table="table" aid:trows="{count(text/table/*/tr)}" aid:tcols="{count(text/table/thead/tr/th)}">
        <xsl:for-each select="text/table/*/tr/*">
            <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="40">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </Cell>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your reply, tried this XSLT and I kind of understand what you are doing but when apply it to the XML it only outputs the first line of the table and no other elements as you can see here: http://xsltransform.net/jxN8NpY/19, maybe something is missing?

Comment: You are not using the same input as the one you posted here. You need to adjust all paths to `table` to fit the actual hierarchy of the input.

Comment: You are right, somehow I forgot that I used a simplified version of the XML, works perfectly now, Thanks! What do you think would be the best approach to clone the rest of the elements, maybe something like the identity transform I'm using in my original xsl? (I know, should have specified that).

Comment: Probably. I would need to see the entire picture to be sure.